# ChartJs - Footer color dynamically

Tags: javascript, chart.js

is there a chance to change the color of the "footer" elements depending on it's value?
This is my current footer - callback where the sum is calculated and my goal is to change the font color to red if it is negative.

I'm trying to prevent using a "html - content tooltip" as always suggested because the positing of it seems a little bit tricky and the canvas one does a pretty good job.

```
 footer: function (tooltipItems) {
           let sum = tooltipItems[0].parsed.y - tooltipItems[1].parsed.y;
           sum = appCore.formatNumber(sum, page.pc(), true, true);
           return `${page.translations['label.sum']}: ${sum}`;
 },
```

Within the documentation  I've found "footerColor" but it seems the value can only set once? I tried the following in the footer method:

```
chart.instance.options.plugins.tooltip.footerColor = (sum >= 0) ?  '#283823' : '#762552';
```

"chart" is my global instance which I've stored during the initialization of the chart.

I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Thanks, Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know where you get the instance part from since its not on the chart if I log it. But yes its possible, you can either do it globally (first outcommented line), you can do it for a specific chart at creation (second outcommented line) or for a specific chart after creation (last line)

```js
//Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.footerColor =  (ctx) => (ctx.tooltip.dataPoints[0].parsed.y > 10 ? 'green' : 'red')

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          footer: () => ('fff')
        },
        //footerColor: (ctx) => (ctx.tooltip.dataPoints[0].parsed.y > 10 ? 'green' : 'red')
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

chart.options.plugins.tooltip.footerColor = (ctx) => (ctx.tooltip.dataPoints[0].parsed.y > 10 ? 'green' : 'red');
chart.update();
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi LeeLenalee, thank you so much . I've opt for the second option: 

footerColor: (ctx) => ((ctx.tooltip.dataPoints[0].parsed.y - ctx.tooltip.dataPoints[1].parsed.y) > 10 ? 'green' : 'red')